# How to hide cmd window of python program which runs commands in cmd?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, operating-system

I am trying to make a simple python program that runs a command in the terminal and then closes at input.

```
import os
os.system("ping google.com")
input()
```

The program runs: it shows the logs and then waits for the input.
Now, I want to make the terminal invisible. I tried with .pyw extension, but it when it ran, it showed the terminal and then closed, no input. How do I make it run without showing the terminal at all?

Comment: How are you getting input if you want to close the cmd prompt right at the run-time.

Comment: I had input at first so it didn't automatically close after it finished. Now I removed it, but it still shows the cmd tab popping up.